# Highlighted Vehicle Icons

Tags: battlefield-3

Why are Tank Destroyer and Mobile AA icons highlighted as can be seen on the screenshot?

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: In what way are they highlighted? I can't see anything obvious...

Comment: I can see the highlighting, but I doubt it means anything.

Comment: Isn't the difference between MBT and Tank Destroyer obvious? A blue halo type background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tank Destroyer" and "Mobile Artillery" was added in DLC "Armored Kill". I think, may be designers wanted to mark DLC content. This is just my guess.

Comment: That's a nice guess. Let's wait a little bit for more answers.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, it is probably not "highlighted". I cannot be sure but it is probably because of the background and anyway, I don't suppose that this will affect your gameplay.

Comment: I don't suppose either, but I am not definitely sure.